# Saving int/byte/string data types in Android

Tags: android, save

Sorry, this might be quite a lengthy question, but how do i actually save int/byte/string data types in Android?

I do know that to save a String into the internal memory (note, not external or anything else), i have to do something like this:

> String FILENAME = "hello_file";
>
> String string = "hello world!";
>
> FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
>
> fos.write(string.getBytes());
>
> fos.close();

to save the file, and:

> int saveTest = fos.read();
>
> fos.close();

to read the file from another activity or something. (Is this correct?)

But what if i want to save and read the file as an int/byte data file? Is this possible? And how would i be able to do it?

Comment: Why not use SharedPreferences instead? It automates the saving/loading of any files, and designed for storing basic datatypes.

Comment: I want the user to be able to save his file inside the main activity, while accessing what he/she has saved inside a widget. I don't think a sharedpref resource would enable me to do that...

Comment: SharedPreferences would work perfectly in fact for this scenario! You can call `getSharedPreferences` in your widget provider to get the saved data.

Comment: but that would only work for a single file, right? i want the user to be able to save lots of files into a stored location and then the widget will be able to access such created files conveniently from such said location...

Comment: Okay, i just read the documentations, seems that it'll be easier to implement it as a sharedpreference as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save your objects you can use the ObjectOutput class to serialize them, e.g.:

```
// Example object which implements Serializable 
Example example = new Example();

// Save an object 
ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(getCacheDir(),"")+"cacheFile.srl"));
out.writeObject( new Integer( YOUR_INT ) );
out.close();


// Load in an object
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(new File(getCacheDir(),"")+"cacheFile.srl")));
Integer example_loaded = (Integer) in.readObject();
in.close();
```

Where the class Example could be any object that implements serializable or byte data, the [javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutput.html) may also help!

Hope this helps!

Comment: what do you mean, "serializable or byte data"? does an int count as that?

Comment: If an object implements serializable, it can be saved using the objectoutput class. I've edited the above example to show how you would save an int.

Comment: If you want to find out more about serializable objects this is a great read: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the link! One more tiny question -- does this affect any performance since i'm working with Android and not purely Java?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read objects, then you would create an `ObjectInputStream` from the `FileInputStream` you got. If you want to read the file as binary, then you can use the `read` member function that works with a `byte[]`.

Comment: Do you have any specifics on how to do that? I don't really understand what you're doing here :S

Comment: Do you mean objects as in Strings,Int,Bytes? I'm sorry, i'm a bit new to programming and i'm still learning the technical ropes. I want to save a file with the main activity and then access the file/s from a widget automatically, if you want to know what i'm actually trying to do, that is.

Comment: the thing is, i don't understand how the saving and reading works, and that gets me a tad bit confused :S